# ps -e converts process name to lowercase

Tags: linux, command-line, ps

`ps -e` converts uppercase process names to lowercase.  I could not find an explanation of that behaviour in the man page or online and I'm not good enough at source code reading to figure this out from that.

I normally use `ps -ef` (full-format listing) so had never noticed this behaviour but a DBA did.

Is `-e` lowercasing a process line expected behaviour?  Does anyone have an explanation as to why it was coded to convert to lowercase?

Here is an example of the same processes, but with `-e` and then with `-ef`:

```
server ~> ps -e | grep -Ei pmon
2187719 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_foobar
2188497 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_phuuba
2188928 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_kilgor
[printed as lowercase when instance name (end of line) should be uppercase ]

server ~> ps -ef | grep -Ei pmon
oracle   2187719       1  0 04:00 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_FOOBAR
oracle   2188497       1  0 04:00 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_PHUUBAR
oracle   2188928       1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_KILGORE
[prints upper case, which is good]
```

`-e` alone also truncates, but that's why we've got `-f`.  Mainly curious about `-e` lowercasing processes.

Comment: It's easily checked if _`ps`_ is doing the changing: just create an executable with name containing uppercase characters (e.g., `cp "$(command -v sleep)"  ./somE_COmmand; ./somE_COmmand INF)`, run it and check `ps -e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps` with and without `-f` give different information in the `CMD` column.

On Linux,

- **Without -f**, that's the *process name*. An attribute of the process with a length limited to 15 bytes. That attribute is set by the `execve()` system call (used to execute command) to the base name of the file being executed, truncated to 15 bytes, and can also be set by the process to arbitrary values using `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)`. It's the same as returned by `ps -o comm`. It can be seen in `/proc/pid/stat` inside `(...)` or in the `Name:` field in `/proc/pid/status`.
- **With -f**, that's the *argument list* joined with space characters¹. Those are the arguments (including `argv[0]`) passed in the second argument to the `execve()` system call for those process which have executed a command (or any of their ancestor). The arg list can be seen NUL-delimited in `/proc/pid/cmdline`. It's the same as returned by `ps -o args`. It used to be truncated to 4096 bytes, but it isn't any longer in recent versions of Linux (though `ps` will truncate it itself for output unless given `-w` options). Processes can (with restriction) change that by writing new text at the section of their stack where that information is found.

`/proc/pid/exe` will also be a symlink to the executable that the process is currently running (as reported by `ps -o exe`), which may also be different.

In any case, other than escaping unprintable characters, `ps` does no transformation on those.

You can run:

```
ps -wwo comm,args,exe -p 2187719
```

To see process name, arg list and executable for the process of id 2187719. And you can check the raw source where `ps` gets that information from with:

```
cat /proc/2187719/stat
sed -n l /proc/2187719/cmdline
readlink /proc/2187719/exe
```

Example:

```
$ cp /usr/bin/sleep 'A longer sleep command for demonstration'
$ (exec -a 'SLEEP though could be anything' './A longer sleep command for demonstration' Infinity) &
[1] 6723
$ ps -fp "$!"
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas    6723    6668  0 06:17 pts/2    00:00:00 SLEEP though could be anything Infinity
$ ps -p "$!"
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   6723 pts/2    00:00:00 A longer sleep
$ cat "/proc/$!/stat"
6723 (A longer sleep ) S 6668 6723 6668 34818 6726 4194304 154 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 25 5 1 0 17863 19312640 448 18446744073709551615 94858855174144 94858855192393 140731919224688 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 94858855206160 94858855207424 94858855886848 140731919232547 140731919232587 140731919232587 140731919237069 0
$ sed -n /Name/l "/proc/$!/status"
Name:\tA longer sleep $
$ sed -n l "/proc/$!/cmdline"
SLEEP though could be anything\000Infinity\000$
$ perl -e '$0 = "whatever you want"; sleep 20' &
[1] 13861
$ ps -wo comm,args,exe -p "$!"
COMMAND         COMMAND                     EXE
whatever you wa whatever you want           /usr/bin/perl
```

In your case, if there's a variation in case, it could be because

- those processes did `execve("/path/to/ora_pmon_foobar", ["ora_pmon_FOOBAR", NULL], envlist);`
- they did `execve("/path/to/anything", ["ora_pmon_FOOBAR", NULL], envlist)` (where `anything` could also be `ora_pmon_FOOBAR`) but later did a `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "ora_pmon_foobar")`.
- They did `execve("/path/to/ora_pmon_foobar", ["ora_pmon_foobar", NULL], envlist);` but later overwrote their `argv[0]` with `ora_pmon_FOOBAR`.

Or combinations of the above. For instance, in `perl`, assigning to `$0` changes both the process name and arg list as seen in the example above.

---

<sup>¹ Except when that argument list is empty like when `execve()` was called by the process with an empty list as the second argument (resulting in `argc` == 0), or for processes where neither them nor any of their ancestors ever called `execve()` like for kernel tasks. In that case, `ps -f` shows the process/task name inside square brackets.</sup>

Comment: Thank you Stephane for the very helpful explanation.  I always learn a lot from your posts.  And like muru suggested, I tested a non-Oracle script and, as expected, that shows no case change.   Thanks again!